# Apache with mod_wsgi - how to reject requests if all threads are busy?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

We have a server that is running Apache and one of the vhosts is using mod_wsgi to run a heavy task on request. The server can handle X requests at a time and each of them will run for ~10 minutes. Rather than making new clients wait if all threads are busy, I'd like to have the server immediately respond with a 503 status if no thread is free.

I tried to use various timeouts to achieve this, but it doesn't work as desired. This is what I tried (with just one thread), but it makes new clients wait for 1800 seconds and responds then with a 504 status.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess xxx user=xxx group=xxx processes=1 threads=1 connect-timeout=10 queue-timeout=10 deadlock-timeout=2000 socket-timeout=1800 listen-backlog=0
```

How can I make the server accept only as many connections as there are threads for the WSGI daemon?

(the server is running Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi 4.5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maxclients directive in apache configuration to limit the number of request apache can serve.

For example :

MaxClients 200

Will allow only 200 clients at the same time.

(edit)

If one vhost has particular problems or specificities, it's often a good idea to isolate it on a dedicated apache instance (can be on the same hardware).

You can try to limit connections on a per vhost basis, but according to this post, you need extra module like mod_cban [Apache Limiting Connections Per VHOST](https://serverfault.com/questions/276478/apache-limiting-connections-per-vhost)

(/edit)

Comment: But this is per server, not per vhost. We have other vhosts that should not be limited.

Comment: Exactly. Then you can can have one apache server for this particular vhost and another apache server for all the others vhosts. (using network magic or reverse proxy can help if you have only one IP adress)

Comment: internet also talks about mod_vhost_limit

Comment: serverfault also talks about mod_cban http://serverfault.com/questions/276478/apache-limiting-connections-per-vhost